# Why does this clang code fail to compile with clang 10 with -std=c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

Following program fails to compile with clang10 and -std=c++20

```
#include "clang/AST/ASTContext.h"
int main(){}
```

With -std=c++17 it works.

This is the compile attempt output(note that I am fine with linker error in C++17 since I did not give the required -l to the command line)

```
clang++-10  toy.cc -I/usr/lib/llvm-10/include -std=c++20 -w
In file included from toy.cc:1:
In file included from /usr/lib/llvm-10/include/clang/AST/ASTContext.h:28:
In file included from /usr/lib/llvm-10/include/clang/AST/RawCommentList.h:14:
/usr/lib/llvm-10/include/clang/Basic/SourceManager.h:953:59: error: use of overloaded operator '!=' is ambiguous (with operand types 'llvm::DenseMapBase<llvm::DenseMap<const clang::FileEntry *, const clang::FileEntry *, llvm::DenseMapInfo<const clang::FileEntry *>, llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<const clang::FileEntry *, const clang::FileEntry *> >, const clang::FileEntry *, const clang::FileEntry *, llvm::DenseMapInfo<const clang::FileEntry *>, llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<const clang::FileEntry *, const clang::FileEntry *> >::iterator' (aka 'DenseMapIterator<const clang::FileEntry *, const clang::FileEntry *, llvm::DenseMapInfo<const clang::FileEntry *>, llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<const clang::FileEntry *, const clang::FileEntry *> >') and 'llvm::DenseMapBase<llvm::DenseMap<const clang::FileEntry *, const clang::FileEntry *, llvm::DenseMapInfo<const clang::FileEntry *>, llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<const clang::FileEntry *, const clang::FileEntry *> >, const clang::FileEntry *, const clang::FileEntry *, llvm::DenseMapInfo<const clang::FileEntry *>, llvm::detail::DenseMapPair<const clang::FileEntry *, const clang::FileEntry *> >::iterator')
      if (OverriddenFilesInfo->OverriddenFiles.find(File) !=
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/lib/llvm-10/include/llvm/ADT/DenseMap.h:1222:8: note: candidate function
  bool operator!=(const ConstIterator &RHS) const {
       ^
/usr/lib/llvm-10/include/llvm/ADT/DenseMap.h:1215:8: note: candidate function
  bool operator==(const ConstIterator &RHS) const {
       ^
/usr/lib/llvm-10/include/llvm/ADT/DenseMap.h:1215:8: note: candidate function (with reversed parameter order)
1 error generated.
clang++-10  toy.cc -I/usr/lib/llvm-10/include -std=c++17 -w
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/toy-4396eb.o:(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `llvm::DisableABIBreakingChecks'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Notes:

- tagged this spaceship since I am not aware of the tag that relates to
  != == changes in C++20
- could not reduce this example since DenseMap is a monster of a class,
  I found similar question, solution there was that operators are
  missing a const qualifier, that does not seem to be a problem here(I
  can see the const in the source), and when I tried to get the similar
  error for a simple case I failed to get an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This LLVM example reduces to:

```
struct iterator;

struct const_iterator {
    const_iterator(iterator const&);
};

struct iterator {
    bool operator==(const_iterator const&) const;
    bool operator!=(const_iterator const&) const;
};

bool b = iterator{} != iterator{};
```

In C++17, this is fine: we only have one candidate and it's viable (`iterator` is convertible to `const_iterator` so that one works).

In C++20, we suddenly have three candidates. I'm going to write them out using non-member syntax so the parameters are more obvious:

```
bool operator==(iterator const&, const_iterator const&); // #1
bool operator==(const_iterator const&, iterator const&); // #2 (reversed #1)
bool operator!=(iterator const&, const_iterator const&); // #3
```

`#2` is the reversed candidate for `#1`. There is no reversed candidate for `#3` because only the primary comparison operators (`==` and `<=>`) get reversed candidates.

Now, the first step in overload resolution is doing conversion sequences. We have two arguments of type `iterator`: for `#1`, that's an exact match/conversion. For `#2`, that's conversion/exact match. For `#3`, that's exact match/conversion. The problem here is we have this "flip-flop" between `#1` and `#2`: each is better in one parameter/argument pair and worse in the other. That's ambiguous. Even if `#3` is the "better candidate" in some sense, we don't get that far - ambiguous conversion sequence means ambiguous overload resolution.

---

Now, gcc compiles this *anyway* (I'm not entirely sure what specific rules it implements here) and even clang doesn't even consider this an error, just a warning (which you can disable with `-Wno-ambiguous-reversed-operator`). There's some ongoing work in trying to resolve these situations more gracefully.

---

To be slightly more helpful, here is a more direct reduction of the LLVM example along with how we could fix it for C++20:

```
template <bool Const>
struct iterator {
    using const_iterator = iterator<true>;

    iterator();

    template <bool B, std::enable_if_t<(Const && !B), int> = 0>
    iterator(iterator<B> const&);

#if __cpp_impl_three_way_comparison >= 201902
    bool operator==(iterator const&) const;
#else
    bool operator==(const_iterator const&) const;
    bool operator!=(const_iterator const&) const;
#endif
};
```

In C++20, we *only* need the one, homogeneous comparison operator.

This didn't work in C++17 because of wanting to support the `iterator<false>{} == iterator<true>{}` case: the only candidate there is `iterator<false>::operator==(iterator<false>)`, and you can't convert a `const_iterator` to an `iterator`.

But in C++20 it's fine, because in this case now we have *two* candidates: `iterator<false>`'s equality operator *and* `iterator<true>`'s reversed equality operator. The former isn't viable, but the latter is and works fine.

We also only need the `operator==`. The `operator!=` we just get for free, since all we want is negated equality.

Alternatively, you could, still in C++17, write the comparison operators as hidden friends:

```
friend bool operator==(iterator const&, iterator const&);
friend bool operator!=(iterator const&, iterator const&);
```

Which gets you the same behavior as C++20, by way of having candidates from both types participate (it's just having to write one extra function as compared to the C++20 version, and that function must be a hidden friend - it cannot be a member).

Comment: great answer, only thing is that I thought I disabled all the warnings with -w, but I guess that is just me misunderstanding the compiler options.
Also this seems to be something Richard Smith/WG21 is familiar with : https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=cfe-users@lists.llvm.org&q=subject:%22%5C%5Bcfe%5C-users%5C%5D+Final+C%5C%2B%5C%2B20+rules+and+%5C-Wambiguous%5C-reversed%5C-operator%22&o=newest&f=1

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Yeah, Richard Smith is generally familiar with everything :-). I couldn't reproduce the issue exactly from the OP, but I went ahead and submitted a [review](https://reviews.llvm.org/D78919) to fix it.

Comment: mild offtopic but do you still prefer free == functions instead of member ones? I think foonathan suggests to make them member so you get less candidates in error message when you mess up. If this is too much offtopic I will make another question.

Comment: for posterity: merge request with examples expanded to https://reviews.llvm.org/D78938

Comment: "and even clang doesn't even consider this an error, just a warning" Actually it is error and option doesn't help: https://godbolt.org/z/jWYGdd

Comment: @MateuszL Depends on the case, it does here: https://godbolt.org/z/cM78hE